# Implicit conversion of 'int; to 'UIImage*' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: xcode

```
-(void)placeHole {
    randomBlackHole = arc4random() %410;
    randomBlackHole = randomBlackHole -10;
    blackHole = randomBlackHole;
}
```

`randomBlackHole` is an integer and `blackHole` is an image within a button.

Comment: Your question is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly. Implicit conversion of int to UIImage* is not allowed. Not with ARC, not without ARC. Not in C, C++, Objective-C, Java, or most other languages. What would it do? Do you think it should turn a number into an image?

BTW. It is highly recommended to start instance variables with an underscore character, so there is a clear distinction between using properties and using instance variables.

Comment: Better yet, use properties instead of instance variables.